# Stop form action on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there any way to stop form action when I have Error on change event..

```
$(".accuplod").change(function(){
    $(".errorjp").remove();
    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    var arr = [ 'png', "jpeg", "jpg" ];

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var extarr = files[i].name.split(".");
        extntn = extarr[1].toLowerCase();

        if (files[i].size > 250000) {
            $(".accclass").after("<div class='errorjp'><label class='form-error'>There was an upload error.Make sure the file " + files[i].name + " having given size.</label></div>");
            // here I want to stop the form action   
        }

        if ($.inArray(extntn, arr) == -1) {
            $(".accclass").after("<div class='errorjp'><label class='form-error'>There was an upload error.Make sure the file " + files[i].name + " is JPG, JPEG, or PNG.</label></div>");
            // here I want to stop the form action 
        }
    }
});
```

How can I stop the form action when there is any error in file upload function on above?

Comment: Stop how exactly? You could just clear the inputs value, if that's what you want.

Comment: you can see the error messages in for loop. when An error message is showed the form is going to submit now. but I want to prevent the submisssion.

Comment: What's actually submitting your form? You can use `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/. But the change event you are listening to is not registered on a form?

Comment: return false is not working

Comment: maybe you just want to hide the submit button or the whole form when error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a submit handler to the form that does something like the following...

```
$(formSelector).on('submit', function(e){
    if ($(".accclass").find(".errorjp").length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Submit was cancelled.  An error exists.');
    }
});
```

This is assuming that they change the input, get the error, and then submit the form, as I don't see your logic doing a submit.